# How remove title of widget 'Step'

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, title, step

During the implementation of the 'Stepper' widget that uses the 'Step' widgets, I couldn't assign a 'null' title, it requires a 'Text'. How can I assign title 'Null' in 'Step' so that there is no spacing between steps for the title.

- Placing the 'Text' widget with empty text does not resolve because the spacing between the 'Step' buttons and the line still exists.
- I would like to take the space between the division lines and the step buttons

Example: Step(
        title: null,
        content: _stepOne(),
)

Comment: If you check Step documentation (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Step-class.html) you'll see that title is required so you can't pass null to it, what you can try is passing en empty Container()

Answer (score 0):

Adding an empty string text widget will do the magic, see code below

Step( title: TExt(''), content: _stepOne(), )